$\exp (T)-I$ compact implies $T$ compact [Result is false]
[Note: The following result is false. See the answer to this question.]
Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $T$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$. Problem 7.10 of the book "Functional Analysis" by van Neerven asks the reader to show that $T$ is compact if and only if $\exp (T) - I$ is compact. My difficulty is with showing $\exp (T) - I$ being compact implies $T$ is compact.
The following hint is provided for the problem.

Hint: To prove the implication $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ show that for large enough integers $k$ we have $T = (\exp (kT) - I)f_{k}(T)$, where $f_{k}(z) = z / (e^{kz} - 1)$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma (T)$.

Here is what I have tried so far. Suppose $\exp (T) - I$ is compact and let $k$ be a positive integer. Since the collection of compact operators form an ideal in the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators on $X$, the equation $\exp (kT) - I = (\exp (T) - I)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\exp (jT)$ shows that $\exp (kT) - I$ is compact. Suppose $f_{k}$ is defined as in the hint. If it is shown that $f_{k}$ is holomorphic on an open set $U$ containing $\sigma (T)$, it follows that $f_{k}(T)$ can be defined using holomorphic functional calculus. Then the algebra homomorphism induced by holomorphic functional calculus shows that $T = (\exp (kT) - I) f_{k}(T)$, from which it would follow that $T$ is compact.
It is readily observed that $f_{k}$ is holomorphic everywhere it is defined and has a removable singularity at $0$. The only complex values $z$ where $f_{k}$ is not holomorphic is when $e^{kz} - 1 = 0$ and $z\neq 0$. This occurs precisely when $kz$ is a non-zero integer multiple of $2\pi i$ and this occurs if and only if $z$ is a non-zero integer multiple of $2\pi i/k$. I assume the idea here is that as $k$ increases, the non-zero integer multiples of $2\pi i/k$ should not intersect $\sigma (T)$. But as an example of what can occur, define $S$ as a bounded linear operator on $\ell_{2}$ by $S(x) := (\frac{2\pi i}{n} x(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then $\exp (S) - I$ is compact because $S$ is compact, but for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the intersection of $\sigma (S)$ with the set of non-zero integer multiples of $2\pi i/k$ is non-empty as $[S - (2\pi i / k)I](e_{k}) 
= 0$. So it is not clear, at least to me, how $k$ can be made arbitrarily large to ensure that $f_{k}$ is holomorphic on $\sigma (T)$ if $T$ is any arbitrary bounded linear operator on $X$.
On the other hand, if $k$ is a positive real number, the non-zero integer multiples of $2\pi i/k$ are bounded below in modulus by $2\pi/k$ which becomes arbitrarily large as $k$ decreases. Since $\sigma (T)$ is a bounded subset of the complex plane, this can be used to make $f_{k}$ holomorphic in an open neighbourhood of $\sigma (T)$. However, as far as I can see you can no longer express $\exp (kT) - I$ in terms of $\exp (T) - I$ to ensure that $\exp (kT) - I$ is compact if $k$ is no longer assumed to be a positive integer. On another note, this observation shows that the result can be obtained if it shown that $\exp (T) - I$ being compact implies that $\exp (sT) - I$ is compact for sufficiently small positive numbers $s$.
I am looking for any way to prove the desired result. If it is possible, it would be preferable that the proof makes use of the hint in the question.

The claim may be false: what if $T$ is $2i\pi$ times the identity?

@Aphelli Thanks for the example. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

As I wrote, this statement is false, since $e^{2i\pi \cdot\mathrm{id}}-1$ is zero, while $2i\pi \cdot\mathrm{id}$ is not compact (unless $X$ is finite-dimensional).
I am not entirely sure how to best repair it. I think it works if the maximal modulus of spectral value of $T$ is less than $2\pi$, since you can write $z=(e^z-1)\cdot \frac{z}{e^{z}-1}$, where the second factor is the sum of a power series with convergence radius $2\pi$.

Thanks for the answer. If the spectrum of the linear operator is contained in the strip ${z\in \mathbb{C} : -2\pi < {\rm Im}(z) < 2\pi }$ then the result is true. In particular, it is true when $X$ is a complex Hilbert space and $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on $X$.
